# "Can't wait without a fiber" error when querying db?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I have the following code that reads a CSV file and then pulls a document from the database:

```
fs.readFile process.env.PWD + '/data/errorports.csv', 'utf8', (err, data) ->
    if err
      console.log "Error reading csv", err
      return
    rows = data.split('\n')
    for row in rows
      columns = row.split(',')
      airportCode = columns[0]
      airport = Airports.findOne({_id: airportCode})
      console.log 'airport:', airport
```

But when I call `Airports.findOne({_id: airportCode})` it throws the error:

```
/Users/abemiessler/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4.19lp8gr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:159
   throw new Error('Can\'t wait without a fiber');
         ^
Error: Can't wait without a fiber
```

Can anyone see why I would be getting this error?  Any suggestions on how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make use of [`Meteor.wrapAsync()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync) to do this (to make your async function run inside a Fider...which will allow you to execute your meteor code inside).  Here is an example.

```
var syncReadFile = Meteor.wrapAsync(fs.readFile);

syncReadFile(process.env.PWD + '/data/errorports.csv', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log "Error reading csv", err;
      return;
    }

    rows = data.split('\n');
    for (row in rows) {
      columns = row.split(',');
      airportCode = columns[0];
      airport = Airports.findOne({_id: airportCode});
      console.log 'airport:', airport;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or ... you can try to wrap your callback into

`Meteor.bindEnvironment()`

Would be something like

```
fs.readFile process.env.PWD + '/data/errorports.csv', 'utf8',
Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, data) {
  [..your code..]
});
```